# How to print out the values in a protobuf message

Tags: protocol-buffers

I know there is a way to serialize a message in protobuf. But is there a easy way to print out the values in a protobuf message? Something like a toString() method in Java?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[protocol buffer basics -- Java](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial)

quoted from the link, check the `standard message methods`:

Standard Message Methods

Each message and builder class also contains a number of other methods that let you check or manipulate the entire message, including:

```
isInitialized(): checks if all the required fields have been set.

toString(): returns a human-readable representation of the message, particularly useful for debugging.

mergeFrom(Message other): (builder only) merges the contents of other into this message, overwriting singular fields and concatenating repeated ones.

clear(): (builder only) clears all the fields back to the empty state.
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I am very very new to Protobuf, still trying to figure out some very basic functionalities. Thanks for the help.

Comment: i used it about 1 or 2 years ago, please see here, a quite simple example: http://haifzhan.blogspot.ca/2013/10/java-generated-code-protocol-buffers.html

Comment: Also, do checkout Class JsonFormat.Printer for advanced conversion!